# Why does `git clone --depth=1 <url>` fail for some repositories with HTTP 500?

Tags: git

I'm using a local deployment of Stash as a Git server.

When cloning certain repositories, like `https://stash.mydomain.net/scm/~be2274/chef-repo.git`, everything works if I clone without `--depth=1`, but fails otherwise:

**`git clone` without `--depth=1`:**

```
$ git clone -v --bare 'https://stash.mydomain.net/scm/~be2274/chef-repo.git'
Cloning into bare repository 'chef-repo.git'...
POST git-upload-pack (gzip 1765 to 943 bytes)
remote: warning: unable to find all commit-graph files
remote: Enumerating objects: 434, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (434/434), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (433/433), done.
remote: Total 14489 (delta 310), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (14489/14489), 1.90 MiB | 646.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (9806/9806), done.
```

**`git clone` with `--depth=1`:**

```
$ git clone -v --bare --depth=1 'https://stash.mydomain.net/scm/~be2274/chef-repo.git'
Cloning into bare repository 'chef-repo.git'...
POST git-upload-pack (180 bytes)
error: RPC failed; HTTP 500 curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Why does Git fail, when `--depth=1` is given as an option to `git clone` to clone only the most recent commit? I have no idea why it's happening, and the error message provides no real information.

What scenarios would make `git clone --depth=1 <url>` fail with `HTTP 500`?

Comment: Check the server-side logs; see if the Git there is terminating early for some reason, and if so, what the reason is.

Comment: @torek - I don't have access to those :(

Comment: Do you know what server is serving git requests on the other end (gitlab, gitolite, gitea, plain git http-backend ...) ? and possibly its version ?

Comment: HTTP status code 500 means internal error on server, you can report this issue to the server provider, ask them to check what happened in background.

Answer (score 0):

A 500 error is defined to be an internal server error, which means that the server encountered some problem that prevented it from completing the request properly.  This is a server-side problem, and as such, you'll need to look at the server logs to find out what's wrong.  Exposing information about internal failures publicly is considered a security risk, so you probably won't be able to find out anything without access to the server.

Since this is a server-side problem, there's nothing you can do to fix it on the client side or otherwise address it there.  You may be able to work around it by choosing not to invoke Git in a way that triggers it, but the defect is on the server and needs to be fixed there.  If there were a problem with what you were doing on the client side, you would have received a 400-series error, not a 500-series error.

If you don't control the server, you should report the problem to the person who does so they can take appropriate steps to address it.